# How to calculate the sum of a text file using methods?

Tags: java, methods, text-files

Assuming that the text file reads: 11 3 6 9 10 7

I am attempting to return the sum of these numbers in the file. Currently, I am returning the listed digits followed by a "0". Not sure where else to take it from here.

Additionally, I would prefer the code be altered from what it is now (I understand that there are BufferReaders, etc., but the assignment I have for class calls that I do the method specifically like this).

```
package module4labs;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Module4Labs {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    new Module4Labs();
}

public Module4Labs() {
        try {
        File outFile = new File("Problem1.txt");
        FileOutputStream outFileStream = new 
FileOutputStream(outFile);
        PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(outFileStream);
        for (int x=0; x<5; x++) {
            pw.print((int)(Math.random()*10)+1 + " ");
        }
        pw.print(Problem1(outFile));
        pw.close();
    }
    catch (FileNotFoundException e){
    }
        try {
            Scanner input = new Scanner(new File("Problem1.txt"));
            while (input.hasNextLine()) {
                System.out.println(input.nextLine());
            }

        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            System.out.println("File Not Found.");
        }   
}
public int Problem1(File file) throws FileNotFoundException {
    int sum =0;
    try {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(new File("Problem1.txt"));  
while(input.hasNextInt()) {
    sum+=input.nextInt();
}
    }
    catch(FileNotFoundException e) {
        System.out.println("File Not Found.");
    }
return sum;
}
```

Comment: In your first part you overwrite the file with "Hello World" (which, as you'll realize are not numbers). Then you read that file, which probably leads to an exception of some kind. Maybe just delete the part where you mess up your input?

Comment: Why are you even overwriting the file? This will make the program work only a single time.

Comment: In you last while loop you have.  `int num = Integer.parseInt("Problem1.txt");` I think it should be. `int num = input.nextInt();`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alrighty, so I found the EXACT answer I was looking for (though I'm sure there are some variations like the one above by Mr. Polywhirl).

```
package module4labs;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Module4Labs {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    new Module4Labs();
}

public Module4Labs() {
        try {
        File outFile = new File("Problem2.txt");
        FileOutputStream outFileStream = new FileOutputStream(outFile);
        PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(outFileStream);
        for (int x=0; x<4; x++) {
            pw.print((int)(Math.random()*10)+1 + ", ");
        }
        pw.print((int)(Math.random()*10));
        pw.println();
        pw.close();
        System.out.println("Sum: "+Problem2(outFile));
    }
    catch (FileNotFoundException e){
        System.out.println("You a dunce");
    }
        try {
            Scanner input = new Scanner(new File("Problem2.txt"));
            while (input.hasNextLine()) {
                System.out.println(input.nextLine());
            }

        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            System.out.println("File Not Found.");
        }       
 }

 //Problem 1: Sum of all numbers in a line
 public int Problem1(File file) throws FileNotFoundException {
    int sum =0;
    try {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(file);
    while(input.hasNextInt()) {
        sum+=input.nextInt();
    }
    input.close();
 } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    System.out.println(file + "File Not Found.");
    }
 return sum;
 }
```

Comment: Basically, I made the sum print out statement a SysOut instead of a pw.print(). Also utilized the file in the method instead of making a new one

Comment: Your approach seems functional by nature. You do not use instance variables; so you shouldn't to instantiate an object. You pass all you need to `Problem1` to get the `int` you need. You could move all the logic from the constructor (`Module4Labs`) into the `main` method. This is abusing the concepts of OOP.

Answer (score 1):

I would create a method that takes two arguments, the input filename and the output filename. I would then create another method that loads a file, sums the values, and returns the result. You can then call this method when writing the output file.

The following program, with no arguments, should produce a file containing the value `46`.

```java
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class Problem {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        if (args.length == 2) {
            process(args[0], args[1]);
        } else {
            process("Problem1.txt", "Problem1_Answer.txt");
        }
    }

    public static void process(String inputFilename, String outputFilename) {
        try {
            FileWriter writer = new FileWriter(outputFilename);
            writer.write(Integer.toString(sumOfIntegers(inputFilename)));
            writer.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static int sumOfIntegers(String inputFilename) {
        Scanner scanner = null;
        int sum = 0;
        try {
            scanner = new Scanner(new File(inputFilename));
            while (scanner.hasNextInt()) {
                sum += scanner.nextInt();
            }
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            if (scanner != null) {
                scanner.close();
            }
        }
        return sum;
    }
}
```